# Is there a way to send an out parameter from a C# controller to an AngularJS JSON call?

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using AngularJS in an ASP.NET MVC page to create a data grid. I have it working with search and sort, and now I'm adding pagination. To do this, I need to have the record count so I know how many pages to show in my pagination links.

My C# Controller has this code:

```
    public JsonResult GetJsonPeople(out int totalRecords, int pageNo = 1, string searchString = "", string sortColumn = "LastName", string sortDirection = "asc")
    {
        var ppl = db.People
            .Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || p.LastName.Contains(searchString))
            .Select(p => new {
                BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID,
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                MiddleName = p.MiddleName,
                LastName = p.LastName,
                Suffix = p.Suffix,
                EmailPromotion = p.EmailPromotion,
                ModifiedDate = p.ModifiedDate })
            .OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortDirection)
            ;

        totalRecords = ppl.Count();

        if (pageSize > 0)
        {
            ppl = ppl.Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        // ViewBag.Search = search;

        var jsonResult = Json(ppl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

My AngularJS call looks like this:

```
var PeopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', []);

PeopleApp.controller('peopleController', ['$scope', '$http', 
function ($scope, $http) {

getPeople();
function getPeople() {
    $http.get('/People/GetJsonPeople')
        .then(function(ppl) {
            $scope.people = ppl.data;
        });
}
$scope.searchPeople = function() {
    $http.get('/People/GetJsonPeople', {
        params:
        {
            "out totalRecords": $scope.totalRecords,
            "pageNo": $scope.pageNo,
            "searchString": $scope.searchText,
            "sortColumn": $scope.sortColumn,
            "sortDirection": $scope.sortDirection
        }
    })
        .then(function (ppl) {
            $scope.people = ppl.data;
        });

}
$scope.sortPeople = function (sortCol) {
    var sortDir;
    if (sortCol == $scope.sortColumn)
        sortDir = $scope.sortDirection == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
    else
        sortDir = "asc";
    $scope.sortDirection = sortDir;
    $scope.sortColumn = sortCol;

    $scope.searchPeople();
}
```

The out parameter isn't working. It's always zero. Can you set an out parameter in the Angular JSON call? If not, how might I get the total count of records into my Angular app model?

I thought of doing a separate $http.get call just to get the record count, but I don't want to burden the database with unnecessary calls. I tried setting a class variable in the controller, setting it in the C# and then returning it from a separate $http.get to return the integer of the count, but since the calls are asynchronous, the first $http.get is never finished before the second one hits, and so it always returns zero.

I'm guessing the answer is easy, but I haven't got it yet.

Comment: I think you need to learn how action binding in ASP.NET MVC works because that's not how `out` parameters work - there is no way it could possibly work (because a HTTP request is fundamentally different to a local in-process function call). You need to pass everything, one-way, in a DTO or parameter.

Comment: Just return it as part of your JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use c# out params with angularjs calls (or any JavaScript calls).

But you could instead return an object which stores the the ppl array and the total count and then return that

```
public JsonResult GetJsonPeople(int pageNo = 1, string searchString = "", string sortColumn = "LastName", string sortDirection = "asc")
{
    var ppl = db.People
        .Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || p.LastName.Contains(searchString))
        .Select(p => new {
            BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID,
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            MiddleName = p.MiddleName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            Suffix = p.Suffix,
            EmailPromotion = p.EmailPromotion,
            ModifiedDate = p.ModifiedDate })
        .OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortDirection)
        ;

    totalRecords = ppl.Count();

    if (pageSize > 0)
    {
        ppl = ppl.Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
    // ViewBag.Search = search;
    var obj = new { ppl = ppl, totalRecords = totalRecords };
    var jsonResult = Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}
```

Then in the client just get the values from the object

```
$scope.searchPeople = function() {
$http.get('/People/GetJsonPeople', {
    params:
    {
        "pageNo": $scope.pageNo,
        "searchString": $scope.searchText,
        "sortColumn": $scope.sortColumn,
        "sortDirection": $scope.sortDirection
    }
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.totalRecords = result.data.totalRecords;
        $scope.people = result.data.ppl;
    });
}
```